# Member couldn`t be used because "poiner-to-incomplete"

Tags: c++, qt

I have a Qt Ui as a pointer as member.
If I try to allocate or use the member in the cpp, it doesn`t work.

There is some extra code which I don`t show because it is not relevant.

Krypto.h:

```
#pragma once
#include <ui_krypto.h>
#include <QMainWindow>

class Krypto : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Krypto(QWidget * parent = NULL);
    ~Krypto();

private:
    Ui::Krypto * Ui = NULL; //This is the Obj which couldn`t be used
};
```

Krypto.cpp:

```
#include "Krypto.h"

Krypto::Krypto(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent)
{
    ui = new Ui::Krypto(); //This don`t work
    ui->setupUi(this); //And this don`t work
}

Krypto::~Krypto()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

ui_krypto.h:

```
class Ui_Krypto
{
public:
    QAction *actionCode_Encode;
    QAction *actionKey;
    QWidget *centralWidget;
    QGroupBox *CodeEncodegroupBox;
    QTextEdit *textausgabe;
    QTextEdit *texteingabe;
    QComboBox *CBAuswahl;
    QCommandLinkButton *ReadyButton;
    QLineEdit *KeyCodelineEdit;
    QLabel *label;
    QGroupBox *KeygroupBox;
    QPushButton *gKeypushButton;
    QLineEdit *keylineEdit;
    ...
    void setupUi(QMainWindow *Krypto)
    {
    ...
    }
}
namespace Ui {
    class Krypto: public Ui_Krypto {};
} // namespace Ui
```

Sorry for the german language but i haven`t found the settings for it.
Here are the failures:
[image: Failures]

Comment: What means "don't work"?

Comment: So what is inside of `<ui_krypto.h>`? It looks like `Ui::Krypto` class definition is missing.

Comment: Sounds like `Ui::Krypto` is only a forward declaration from `<ui_krypto.h>`.

Comment: Please edit your question to post the contents of `ui_krypto.h`.  The exact compiler error messages would be nice too.

Comment: Always copy and paste error messages exactly as they appear.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your class member should be called 'ui' not 'Ui'

```
class Krypto : public QMainWindow
{
    ...

private:
    Ui::Krypto * ui = NULL;
};
```

Comment: (without parenthesis) does not work and there is no overoaded constructor which accept QWidget or QMainwindow

Comment: @WiKoGT72 Green tick mark on the left is supposed to be placed on a correct answer which solved your problem. If this one doesn't help, you should remove it.

Comment: It helped me! I made a simple mistake